# Getting error running smart contract - Invalid tuple format

Tags: solidity

I am trying to deploy a smart contract by passing argument. I am getting repeated errors of invalid tuple even when i am passing in the right format. Can someone assist? I am new to solidity and still learning.

[The tuple format is expected in the circled Wallet param. Also highlighted the Wallet variable declaration on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLN2D.png)

I followed some forums and passed tuple values as array like ["wallet address"] for which i am now getting another error

creation of Jimmy errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: types/value length mismatch (argument="tuple", value=["0x574XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"], code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.7.0)